# ¿Cómo transformar filas por columnas agrupando una variable?

Tags: r

Tengo una serie de datos con la siguiente estructura:

```
datos <- read.table(header=T, text="
id Nombre Sexo
1 Alberto H
1 Luis H
1 Maria M
2 Alberto H
2 Paco H
3 Bea M
3 Marisa M 
3 Josefina M")
```

El objetivo es obtener algo como esto:

```
1  Alberto     Luis    Maria      H      H      M
2  Alberto     Paco               H      H      
3      Bea   Marisa Josefina      M      M      M
```

Comment: Hola! ¿Puedes comentar que has intentado para resolver tu duda?

Comment: Hola, para resolver este problema estuve intentando usar la funcion transpose y la funcion Melt, pero no consigo obtener la transposicion agrupando por la variable id.

library(reshape2)
datos <- melt(x,id=c("id"))

> datos
   id variable    value
1   1   Nombre  Alberto
2   1   Nombre     Luis
3   1   Nombre    Maria
4   2   Nombre  Alberto
5   2   Nombre     Paco
6   3   Nombre      Bea
...

Comment: el paquete tidyr, incluido en el tidyverse tiene una version _mejorada_ de las dcast y metl que existen en reshape2, estas se llaman spread and gather.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty:

```
library(tidyverse) #Para %>%

datos %>% 
split(.$id) %>% 
lapply(function(x) paste(
    paste0(x$Nombre, collapse=" "), 
    paste0(x$Sexo, collapse =" "))) %>% 
cbind() %>% 
as.data.frame() #Pq cbind regresa un matrix

1  Alberto Luis Maria H H M
2          Alberto Paco H H
3 Bea Marisa Josefina M M M
```

Cada fila es un string sin `colnames`, no sé si es lo que buscas.

## Con cada cadena como columna.

Como señala Patricio, no hay soluciones simples o fáciles de generalizar, porque los largos no son iguales y de algún modo hay rellenar con NA. Esta es otra aproximación al problema, similar pero con otro estilo.

```
library(tidyverse)
largo_max <- datos %>% 
               split(.$id) %>% 
               sapply(length) %>% 
               max()    

datos %>% 
  split(.$id) %>% 
  map(~list(paste0(.$Nombre, collapse=" "), paste0(.$Sexo, collapse =" "))) %>% 
  map(as.data.frame) %>%                       #Para que funcione bind_rows() y produzca un data.frame. map_df() sería más directo, pero no coinciden los nombres.
  map(~setNames(., c("nombre", "sexo"))) %>%   #Fuerzo los nombres para que coincidan y bind_rows() no proteste. Esta línea es ad hoc, complicaría generalizar la solución.
  bind_rows() %>%                              #Aquí sale un data.frame
  separate(sexo, paste("sexo", 1:largo_max)) %>% 
  separate(nombre, paste("nombre", 1:largo_max))
```

Comment: No he conseguido que me funcione... Se queda esperando un simbolo para cerrar...
Gracias

Comment: Faltaba un paréntesis para cerrar `lapply()`.

Answer (score 2):

Parece un problema sencillo, pero tiene su complicación en el hecho que no hay una cantidad de filas por `id` consistente, entonces hay que agregar los `NA` correspondientes. Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
datos$Nombre <- as.character(datos$Nombre)
datos$Sexo <- as.character(datos$Sexo)
out <- aggregate(cbind(Nombre, Sexo) ~ id, datos, paste)
out[[2]] <- lapply(out[[2]], FUN = function(x) c(x, rep(NA,max(lengths(out[[2]]))-length(x))))
out[[3]] <- lapply(out[[3]], FUN = function(x) c(x, rep(NA,max(lengths(out[[3]]))-length(x))))
x1 <- do.call(rbind, out$Nombre)
colnames(x1) <- paste0("Nombre_",1:ncol(x1))
x1 <- cbind(out[c("id")], x1)
x2 <- do.call(rbind, out$Sexo)
colnames(x2) <- paste0("Sexo_",1:ncol(x2))
final <- cbind(x1, x2)
final
```

#### Explicación

En primer lugar, para evitar problemas, convertimos las columnas si son `Factor` a una cadena común:

```
datos$Nombre <- as.character(datos$Nombre)
datos$Sexo <- as.character(datos$Sexo)
```

Luego agrupamos por `id` y combinamos los valores de `Nombre` y `Sexo`

```
out <- aggregate(cbind(Nombre, Sexo) ~ id, datos, paste)

out
  id                Nombre    Sexo
1  1  Alberto, Luis, Maria H, H, M
2  2         Alberto, Paco    H, H
3  3 Bea, Marisa, Josefina M, M, M
```

Las columnas `Nombre` y `Sexo` ahora son listas con todos los valores. Lo siguiente es hacer que cada una de estas listas tengan la misma cantidad de valores, agregando `NA`:

```
out[[2]] <- lapply(out[[2]], FUN = function(x) c(x, rep(NA,max(lengths(out[[2]]))-length(x))))
out[[3]] <- lapply(out[[3]], FUN = function(x) c(x, rep(NA,max(lengths(out[[3]]))-length(x))))
```

Por último transformamos cada lista en columnas, y renumeramos cada nombre de columna:

```
x1 <- do.call(rbind, out$Nombre)
colnames(x1) <- paste0("Nombre_",1:ncol(x1))
x1 <- cbind(out[c("id")], x1)
x2 <- do.call(rbind, out$Sexo)
colnames(x2) <- paste0("Sexo_",1:ncol(x2))
final <- cbind(x1, x2)
final
```

La salida final:

```
  id Nombre_1 Nombre_2 Nombre_3 Sexo_1 Sexo_2 Sexo_3
1  1  Alberto     Luis    Maria      H      H      M
2  2  Alberto     Paco     <NA>      H      H   <NA>
3  3      Bea   Marisa Josefina      M      M      M
```

Comment: Una currada, yo buscando una función que lo hiciera pero nada, la siguiente opción que me estaba planteando es un for, pero no me hacen gracia la verdad.
Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa es:

```r
datos <- read.table(header = T, te
 = "
id Nombre Sexo
1 Alberto H
1 Luis H
1 Maria M
2 Alberto H
2 Paco H
3 Bea M
3 Marisa M
3 Josefina M")

library(tidyverse)
```

Para cada Variable creamos una tabla auxiliar de que contiene el numero de fila
agrupado por id

```r
d1 <- datos %>% select(id, Nombre) %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(rn = row_number())
d1
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>      id Nombre      rn
#>   <int> <fct>    <int>
#> 1     1 Alberto      1
#> 2     1 Luis         2
#> 3     1 Maria        3
#> 4     2 Alberto      1
#> 5     2 Paco         2
#> 6     3 Bea          1
#> 7     3 Marisa       2
#> 8     3 Josefina     3
```

Luego usamos la funcion spread para "esparcir" Nombre en funcion de la
variable "rn" (row number)

```r
d11 <- spread(d1, rn, Nombre)
d11
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>      id `1`     `2`    `3`     
#> * <int> <fct>   <fct>  <fct>   
#> 1     1 Alberto Luis   Maria   
#> 2     2 Alberto Paco   <NA>    
#> 3     3 Bea     Marisa Josefina
```

Lo mismo para Sexo.

```r
d2 <- datos %>% select(id, Sexo) %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(rn = row_number())
d2
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>      id Sexo     rn
#>   <int> <fct> <int>
#> 1     1 H         1
#> 2     1 H         2
#> 3     1 M         3
#> 4     2 H         1
#> 5     2 H         2
#> 6     3 M         1
#> 7     3 M         2
#> 8     3 M         3

d22 <- spread(d2, rn, Sexo)
d22
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>      id `1`   `2`   `3`  
#> * <int> <fct> <fct> <fct>
#> 1     1 H     H     M    
#> 2     2 H     H     <NA> 
#> 3     3 M     M     M
```

Un join, para juntar

```r
full_join(d11, d22, by = "id")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#> # Groups:   id [?]
#>      id `1.x`   `2.x`  `3.x`    `1.y` `2.y` `3.y`
#>   <int> <fct>   <fct>  <fct>    <fct> <fct> <fct>
#> 1     1 Alberto Luis   Maria    H     H     M    
#> 2     2 Alberto Paco   <NA>     H     H     <NA> 
#> 3     3 Bea     Marisa Josefina M     M     M
```

En resumen:

```r
d1 <- datos %>% 
  select(id, Nombre) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(rn, Nombre)

d2 <- datos %>% 
  select(id, Sexo) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(rn, Sexo)

full_join(d1, d2, by = "id")
```